# In abundance or too often

Tags: adverbs

If someone says 'Use flipflops in abundance.' What does it imply? What message does this sentence convey? Does this convey the number of flipflops or the frequency of using flipflops? Does it mean that you are being asked to wear flipflops 'too often' or to wear 'many flipflops' at a time?

Comment: Context? Are we talking about the things you wear on your feet, or electronic circuits? If the former, I'd guess the suggestion is about wearing them often. If the latter, I'd guess it's about using a lot of them. It's ambiguous, and possibly an odd way of saying whatever they're trying to say.

Comment: Unless you're a quadruped (or a centipede), the question answers itself.

Comment: The Centipede Political Correctness Bureau is reviewing the previous comment!

Answer (score 2):

"Abundance" is a noun meaning a large amount of something. So this is like saying "Use large amounts of flipflops" or "use a lot of flipflops". It's hard to imagine the context where this would make sense, or sound natural. I could maybe imagine saying to a friend who always wears flip-flops "you use flip-flops in abundance", but that still is a joking use of "abundance".

Using it in a command like "use flip-flops in abundance" just seems strange. It does usually imply more about the number of the thing, rather than frequency of usage. So the problem, that makes the use strange, is that one can typically only use two flip-flops at a time, at least if you are a bipedal human. For me "use flip-flops in abundance" creates an image of someone who has flip-flops hanging all over their body and on top of their head.

A more typical use of "abundance" is to indicate that there is a lot of something, that it is good to have a lot of that something, and there's often an implication that it was produced without any work on the part of the speaker. "There is an abundance of berries in the neighborhood in August" is a typical example.